# Function to check if jquery plugins are already initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

i want to check if jquery plugins are already initialized / included (prevent dublicate resource loading) and if not i want to add the plugin by CDN or by a local source.

Anyone can help me with that Problem?

---

Update:

I'm currently building a custom template in drupal. In that template i'm using a slick slider for scrolling through pictures in a content gallery. I also want to use a custom module for a slideshow, which uses the slick slider too (js, css integrated in the module). So now i want to check if the slick slider of the slideshow module is already initialized, if not i want to load the slick slider js via cdn.

Hope that helps for understanding my problem.

---

Update 2:
Resolved the problem by using php and drupal core functions. I also found a solution with the modernizr.js load function -> asynchronous loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check and detect the plugin using this

```
if(jQuery().pluginName) {
    //run plugin
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
if (!jQuery.fn.plugin) {
    jQuery.getScript('http://url/to/the/script');
}
```

Comment: @MilindAnantwar the question was about jQuery plugins not about jQuery itself.

Comment: Isn't jquery library is a part of it.

Comment: Jquery is already loaded, problem is that i want to prevent that plugins are loaded multiple times...

Answer (score 2):

You can check for typeof jQuery. if undefined, load from CDN:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
{
  //load from CDN  
}
```

or

```
if(!window.jQuery)
{
  //load from CDN  
}
```