# How to identify plugin (croppie or any other) initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, croppie

I use [croppie](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie) for editing pictures before uploading. The task is to destroy and init again this plugin without reloading the page.

So what I've already had:

```
$('#someID').croppie({
   viewport: {
      width: 128,
      height: 128
   }
});
$('#someID').croppie('bind', {
   url: 'some base64 encoded image'
});
```

After some operations - I hide the plugin:

```
$('#someID').toggle();
$('#someID').croppie('bind');
```

After all there are cases when I need [croppie](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie) again and first part of js code works again, so I have in console:

```
croppie.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Croppie: Can't initialize croppie more than once
```

And obviously I just hafta check initialized plugin for current element now or not. What I found:

```
// it supposed to be the answer, however it doesn't work correctly for me.    
if (!jQuery().fn.croppie) {

       $('#someID').croppie({
           viewport: {
                width: 128,
                height: 128
           }
       });

    }
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353415/function-to-check-if-jquery-plugins-are-already-initialized) - and it always `true` ('cause of it's included library and it returns function) and I can't check this way;
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded) the same issue.

So, how to make sure that plugin initialized now or not?

P.S. It could be croppie or any other plugin. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if (!jQuery().fn.croppie)`, check with `if(!$('#someID').data('croppie'))`

```
if(!$('#someID').data('croppie'))
{
 $('#someID').croppie({
       viewport: {
            width: 128,
            height: 128
       }
   });

}
```

Comment: I don't think croppie add such data attribute, may be update your answer to check for class which croppie add?

if(jQuery('.cropimagecontainer').hasClass('croppie-container'))
// destroy croppie
]

Answer (score 0):

In croppie.js only comment the condition at line 1487

```
if (element.className.indexOf('croppie-container') > -1){
  throw new Error("Croppie: Can't initialize croppie more than once");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!!

```
if(!$('#someID').hasClass('croppie-container')){
    $ImageCrop = $('#someID').croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        viewport: viewportval,
        boundary: boundaryval
    });        
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.